# Getting Kafka Streams Class Cast Exception on the same Class while applying map function

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

**UserRecord.java** (autogenerated by Maven Avro plugin)

```
UserRecord extends SpecificRecordBase implement SpecificRecord
```

**UserRecordSerde.java**

```
UserRecordSerde extends SpecificAvroSerde
```

**application.yml**

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination: userTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.useNativeDecoding: true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.valueSerde:UserRecordSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.keySerde: LongSerdespring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde: LongSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde: SpecificAvroSerde
```

### **Class - StreamListener - raw stream comes with null key and UserRecord object in avro**

```
@StreamListener
        public KStream<Long, ArrayList<UserRecord>> handleUserRecords (@Input KStream<?, UserRecord> userRecordStream) { <br/>
        Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = new HashMap();
        serdeConfig.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
        serdeConfig.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true); <br/>
        Serde<ArrayList<UserRecord>> userRecordListSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde();
        userRecordListSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false); <br/>
        return userRecordStream
            .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue(value.getUserID, value)
            .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.Long(), userRecordSerde))
            .aggregate(ArrayList::new, Long key, UserRecord value, ArrayList agg ->
            {
               agg.add(value);
               return agg;
            }, userRecordListSerde)
        .toStream();
    }
```

**exception**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.UserRecord cannot be cast to com.example.UserRecord
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:124)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:46)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
```

Comment: Sounds like your `UserRecordSerde` loads `UserRecord` in different `ClassLoader` than this class with the `handleUserRecords()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you just remove this from the configuration altogether? `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.valueSerde:UserRecordSerde` and simply use the `SpecificAvroSerde` directly through the default configuration.
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde`.

Comment: I tried putting SpecificAvroSerde too, it didn't work. To avoid classloader issue - I added - `System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false"); ` Now i am getting another exception - `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord`

Comment: Could you share your sample app on Github? I will take a closer look.

Comment: Here is a sample where we use Avro Serdes. Take a looks at the `application.yml`. Why don't you compare? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-interactive-query-advanced

Comment: Nice. Could you comment on how you made it work so that if others have the same issue can refer to this?